# Regular expression to match only character or space or one dot between two words, no double space allowed

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help with regular expression.I need a expression in JavaScript which allows only character or space or one dot between two words, no double space allowed.

I am using this

```
var regexp = /^([a-zA-Z]+\s)*[a-zA-Z]+$/;
```

but it's not working.

**Example**

```
1.  hello space .hello - not allowed
2.  space hello space - not allowed
```

Comment: $ - means end of string, also no dash in regex. what actually you need to get?

Comment: Ending space, also no dash Example testing.t not allowed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
^(\s?\.?[a-zA-Z]+)+$
```

**EDIT1**

```
/^(\s{0,1}\.{0,1}[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space ..hello space')
false
/^(\s{0,1}\.{0,1}[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space .hello space')
true
```

v2:

```
/^(\s?\.?[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space .hello space')
true
/^(\s?\.?[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space ..hello space')
false
```

v3:
if you need some thisn like one space or dot between

```
/^([\s\.]?[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space hello space')
true
/^([\s\.]?[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space.hello space')
true
/^([\s\.]?[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space .hello space')
false
```

v4:

```
/^([ \.]?[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space hello space')
true
/^([ \.]?[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space.hello space')
true
/^([ \.]?[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space .hello space')
false
/^([ ]?\.?[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space .hello space')
true
```

**EDIT2**
Explanation:

may be problem in \s = [\r\n\t\f ]
so if only space allowed - `\s?` can be replaced with `[ ]?`

http://regex101.com/r/wV4yY5

Comment: who put -1 and for what?

Comment: I'm not sure. My guess is because there is no explanation for your proposals and there are spelling and formatting mistakes in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

This regular expression will match multiple spaces or dots between words and spaces before the first word or after the last word. This is the opposite of what you want, but you can always invert it (`!foo.match(...)`):

```
/\b[\. ]{2,}\b|^ | $/
```

In regex101.com: http://regex101.com/r/fT0pF2

And in plainer english:

```
\b        => a word boundary
[\. ]     => a dot or a space
{2,}      => 2 or more of the preceding
\b        => another word boundary
|         => OR
^{space}  => space after string start
|         => OR
{space}$  =>  space before string end
```

This will match:

```
"this  that" // <= has two spaces
"this. that" // <= has dot space
" this that" // <= has space before first word
"this that " // <= has space after last word
```

But it will not match:

```
"this.that and the other thing"
```

Comment: So what you propose is looking for an illegal states, whereas the question author is about a positive approach IMHO.

Comment: You're right. I should have made that clear. I decided early on that finding problems reliably would be easier.

Comment: >> no double space allowed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Does he/she want double spaces to be allowed? My understanding is that they should not be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```
^\s*([a-zA-Z]+\s?\.?[a-zA-Z]+)+$
```

This allows:

1. Multiple leading spaces.
2. Space as a delimiter.
3. Dot in the second and any consecutive word.

Comment: Not Working I need allow only characters starting spaces and dots also  for example  1. abcd.ab 2. spaces abcd space .abcd like that

Comment: Maybe be a bit more clear what you mean. Can you put a few examples of legal and illegal values in quotes: `"this is legal"`, `" this.is not "` or whatever? I think we're all confused what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Please update the Q with all your inputs, use quotes in your examples?
So leading multiple or a single space(s) are allowed?

Comment: I need Example : "this is .testing", " more spaces    this .is testing", "this is .testing    "

Answer (score -1):

Try this (only a single whitespace or a period is allowed between the words):

```
> /\w+[\s\.]\w+/.test('foo bar')
true
> /\w+[\s\.]\w+/.test('foo.bar')
true
> /\w+[\s\.]\w+/.test('foo..bar')
false
> /\w+[\s\.]\w+/.test('foo .bar')
false
```